# Arcsine expressed by complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I have found this expression (I am worried about domain issues or any algebraic mistake I make)by playing around with the formula for sine, i.e-

$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
From this, I got->

$$\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\ln|ix \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}|$$

I think I know why there's a plus minus, I propose the following,

We know, $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x$ so plugging sine into formula we get,

$$=-i\ln|i\sin(x)\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}|$$

But since, $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}=|\cos(x)|$ We can split this into cases,

Case (i) $|\cos(x)|=\cos(x)$
Now we want a "+" in the formula so that we can get $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$
So we get,

$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=-i\ln|\cos(x)+i\sin(x)|$

Simplifying this we get,

$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x$

The formula works!

Now similarly we have a "-"  when $|\cos(x)|=-\cos(x)$ for case 2.

Conclusion:Is the following true?

$\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\ln|ix + \sqrt{1-x^2}|$ when $|\cos(x)|=\cos(x)$
and,

$\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\ln|ix - \sqrt{1-x^2}|$ when $|\cos(x)|=-\cos(x)$

Comment: Please use `\sin` for $\sin$ and similar for cos and ln.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the formal definitions we have

$$
\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\sinh^{-1}(ix)\\
\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\big)
$$

and thus

$$
\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\ln(ix+\sqrt{1-x^2}\big)
$$

Notice that there is no $\pm$ here. This is not an oversight. There are $\pm$ in the definitions of $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ as well as other inverse hyperbolic functions. In addition, you suggest that $|\cos(x)|$ can have positive and negative values. That would not be possible.

Comment: Sir, I understand your first statement but I would like to clarify on the second part, by saying "$|cos(x)|=-cos(x)$". I meant that for values like $\pi$, the cosine function is negative so the absolute value for these negative numbers is that negative number multiplied by -1, i.e-  $|cos(\pi)|=-cos(\pi)$

Comment: After taking the derivative,I have recognized that my proposal is false, Thanks sir and sorry if I caused you trouble by my confusing language.

Comment: Of course, I understood what you meant, but it looks funny when you write it that way. I hope that my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: It was a fortune to get answered from someone so experienced.